# Prolog-operator "_:_" - meaning?

Tags: prolog, operator-keyword

I do not understand the following Prolog snippet? 
What does `":_:"` mean? What is the difference between `":="` and `"="` ?

```
game_to_problematic_points(Game,Pid,Hid) :-
  Point := Game/point,
  Pid := Point@id,
  Point = point:_:Hits.
  append(_, [Hit1,_|_], Hits),
  hit_out(Hit1),
  Hid := Hit1@id.
hit_out(Hit) :-
  X := Hit@x,
  Y := Hit@y,
  ( X > 23.77 / 2
  ; X < -23.77 / 2
  ; Y > 10.97 / 2
  ; Y < -10.97 / 2).
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Which Prolog system?

Comment: @PauloMoura SWI-Prolog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be XPCE code. XPCE is the native SWI-Prolog object-oriented GUI library. You can find its manual in PDF format at:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/xpce/doc/userguide/userguide.pdf

The `:=/2` operator is used for assignment (see the guide for details) while the `=/2` is the standard Prolog unification operator.

The goal `Point = point:_:Hits` is simply the unification of the variable `Point` with the compound term `point:_:Hits`. It may be clear if you write this term in canonical form:

```
?- write_canonical(point:_:Hits).
:(point,:(_,_))
true.
```

Note that this term uses the standard `:/2` module operator twice.